# Registry.SetValue() is not working

Tags: c#, windows, registrykey

I'm running my app on Windows 8.1 (64-bit), and I want to create a value in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run`

This is my code:

```
try
{
    // Setting
    RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine;
    // I have to use CreateSubKey 
    // (create or open it if already exits), 
    // 'cause OpenSubKey open a subKey as read-only
    RegistryKey sk1 = rk.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",true);
    // Save the value
    sk1.SetValue("Servicio de Respaldo de Base de Datos", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName.Replace(".vshost", ""));
}
catch 
{
    MessageBox.Show("No se pudo Asignar el Inicio Automatico del servicio", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
}
```

This never enters the catch block, so there is no exception, but the key is never created.

I have already tried the microsoft approach:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run");
key.SetValue("Servicio de Respaldo de Base de Datos", System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName.Replace(".vshost", ""));
key.Close();
```

But get the same result. Can someone can tell me why is this happening and/or how can i make it work?

Comment: Your app 32-bit or 64-bit? Have you looked at `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run` key? Any changes here?

Comment: i'm working on Visual Studio, and i don't really know if it generates a 32 or a 64 bit executable... and yes, i have looked the key in `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run` and there is no changes.

Comment: Did value persists, did you try to read it back? Did you try to search for `Servicio de Respaldo de Base de Datos` string in registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you're still looking for an answer: Do you have sufficient rights to write into HKLM? Else, the entry might enter the VirtualStore without you telling. You can search for your value in the registry as @PetSerAl suggested.